# How to apply conditions to play video in full screen and to play in a certain frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a video by default in full screen according to this:

[Play video by default in full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977330/play-video-by-default-in-full-screen/5977396#comment-6901217)

But using this code minimize control is missing.

My exact requirment is that:

As the view will load a video will play by default in full screen and when it will be minimize it should be play in a certain frame.
And when it will end I want to write some code, but What condition will be apply to check to  whether the video is finish/end?

Plz help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: You are saying that the "minimize control" was missing. Which device are you trying that on - and which iOS version is installed?

Comment: Yes, if I used moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen; then "minimize control" is missing. I have not checked on device, on simulator I have checked and using iOS 4.2 Thanks

Comment: Which iOS SDK version are you linking against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register for the notification as below

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(movieLoaded:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer];
```

and then implement the messages as follows:

```
- (void)movieLoaded:(NSNotification*)notification 
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
```

Comment: what code will I write in - (void)movieLoaded:(NSNotification*)notification

Comment: @Archana The MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification is not needed for your task, ignore that part of Hanuman's answer.

Answer (score 1):

when ever you alloc your moviePlayer object add bellow notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                       object:moviePlayer];
```

so when your video will finish playing or you will finish it by done bellow method will be called:

```
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
// write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi use this its work fine

```
AVAsset *aset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
AVPlayerItem *item=[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:aset];
play=[[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:item];
AVPlayerLayer *layer=[[AVPlayerLayer alloc]init];
layer.player=play;;
layer.frame=CGRectMake(200, 250, 400, 250);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

[play play];
```