# How to play a video from either a local or a server URL in iOS

Tags: ios

How can I play a .mp4 or .mov video from either an Internet URL or a local file in iOS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing a video file from server in an Iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015165/playing-a-video-file-from-server-in-an-iphone-app)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977330/play-video-by-default-in-full-screen/5977396#5977396

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1.First of all add MediaPlayer.Framework in XCode

2.Then add #import < MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h > in your viewController's .h file

3.Now implement this code in your viewDidLoad Method

```
     //NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaa" ofType:@"mp4"];  
     //NSURL    *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];  

     NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

     moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]; 
     [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
     [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];  
     moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;  
     [moviePlayerController play];
```

For Orientation Please add this code

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     // Return YES for supported orientations
          if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
         [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 270)]; 
     } else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
         [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)]; 
     }
     return YES;
 }
```

In this code moviePlayerController is MPMoviePlayerController declared in .h file

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but still relevant and iOS 9 has deprecated MPMoviePlayerController. The new thing to use if AVMoviePlayer, example code:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vid" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
layer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];

[self.avPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this its perfectly working for me,

```
var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width-40, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2)

    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = true

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

}
```

And please enable the **App Transport Security Settings -->Allow Arbitrary Loads-->YES** in Plist file.