# iPhone App :How to play Youtube video in app using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

iPhone App :How to play Youtube video in app using MPMoviePlayerController

for that  i write the code:

```
 NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.youtube.com/xyz";
 NSLog(@"URL ADDress : %@",urlAddress);

 //Create a URL object.
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
movie.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
[self.view addSubview:movie.view];
[movie play];
```

if i pass the url of local directory it is playing video

```
 NSString* filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Video.mp4"];
NSURL* url = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath] autorelease];
```

How can I play video directly from youtube url to MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play Video in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026942/how-to-play-local-and-server-url-video-in-iphone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great thread that on IphoneDevSDk.

They work with a hidden UIWebView:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/61447-how-play-youtube-movie.html

Comment: I tried this here: https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor, but it's a very flaky solution and doesn't work well with iOS5. Google clearly doesn't like it. If only the UIWebView plugin wouldn't be SO shitty.

Answer (score -3):

```
  NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com/path/to/movie.mp4";
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
  [moviePlayer play];
```

Check this and release the controller.

Comment: @rckoenes why not ?? i have played youtube by downloading it and saved in local ...another mean of playing is embedding the youtube link and playing in safari