# Swift 4 & Xcode 10. Play video on app launch, when complete, reveal view controller

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

Firstly, I'm totally new to Xcode 10 and Swift 4, and I've searched here but haven't found code that works.

What I'm after:
On launching app to play a video which is stored locally (called "launchvideo").
On completion of video to display/move to a UIviewcontroller with a storyboard ID of "menu"

So far I have my main navigation controller with it's linked view controller.
I'm guessing I need a UIview to hold the video to be played in on this page?

Is there someone who can help a new guy out?
Thanks

Comment: If you mean launchscreen then you cant put video in there. Do you?

Comment: If you want to play a video right after launchScreen ended then try search for `AVPlayerLayer`, it should be enough to play the video

Comment: No not on the launchscreen.  I understand you can't play a video there. This will have a static image until the app loads.

Comment: @Astro, As Tj3n Suggested, you need to play the launchVideo in UIViewController probably in viewDidAppear delegate method after all the UI elements are loaded. PLease have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026942/how-to-play-a-video-from-either-a-local-or-a-server-url-in-ios

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly change your launch screen storyboard to Main storyboard from project settings in General tab.

Create one view controller with following name and write code to implement AVPlayer to play video.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoLaunchVC: UIViewController {

    func setupAVPlayer() {

        let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Video", withExtension: "mov") // Get video url
        let avAssets = AVAsset(url: videoURL!) // Create assets to get duration of video.
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!) // Create avPlayer instance
        let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer) // Create avPlayerLayer instance
        avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds // Set bounds of avPlayerLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer) // Add avPlayerLayer to view's layer.
        avPlayer.play() // Play video

        // Add observer for every second to check video completed or not,
        // If video play is completed then redirect to desire view controller.
        avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 1) , queue: .main) { [weak self] time in

            if time == avAssets.duration {
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.setupAVPlayer()  // Call method to setup AVPlayer & AVPlayerLayer to play video
    }
}
```

**Main.Storyboard:**
[image: Video Launch VC]

**Project Launch Screen File:**
[image: Project Launch Screen File]

See following video also:

https://youtu.be/dvi0JKEpNTc

Comment: i must still be doing something wrong.  I get a build error with this line: "  let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController"

i'm guessing this has to do with the destination view controller... have i not named it correctly?

Comment: This is just solution of your problems. You must need to use your view controllers and identifier which are you using for same. Show me your storyboard with identifier and view controller.

Comment: i've posted the storyboard below

Comment: Are you able to package your files and supply so i can use?  It will help me learn too

Comment: Hi again @sagar , are you able to help further?

Comment: @Astro, I have shared demo project at following link, please check it: https://ufile.io/cery8

Comment: Thankyou so much.  I will look at this later today, it will help me trouble shoot my error :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to load a video on **launchvideoVC**, like below way in **swift 4 and above**

```
 import AVFoundation
 import AVKit

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    initVideo()
 }

func initVideo(){
    do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourlocalvideo", ofType:"mp4");
    player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!) as URL)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(launchvideoVC.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player?.currentItem)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.zPosition = 1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        self.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        self.player?.play()

    })
}

@objc func itemDidFinishPlaying(_ notification: Notification?) {
   //move to whatever UIViewcontroller with a storyboard ID of "menu"
}
```

I think it's may help you.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

First you make a new view controller with view and change your launch screen storyboard to Main storyboard from project settings in General tab.

[image]

And also add your video in folder.

[image]

Then just add my below code to your launch screenView controller:

```
import UIKit

import MediaPlayer

import AVKit

class LaunchViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate var rootViewController: UIViewController? = nil

    var player: AVPlayer?

    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        showSplashViewController()



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    func playVideo() {

        let videoURL = NSURL(string: "videoplayback")

        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)

        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player

        self.addChildViewController(playerController)



        // Add your view Frame

        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame



        // Add subview in your view

        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)



        player?.play()

    }

    private func loadVideo() {



        //this line is important to prevent background music stop

        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)

        } catch { }



        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoplayback", ofType:"mp4")



        let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)

        let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)



        playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame

        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        playerLayer.zPosition = -1



        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)





        player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

        player.play()

    }



    func showSplashViewControllerNoPing() {



        if rootViewController is LaunchViewController {

            return

        }



        loadVideo()

    }



    /// Simulates an API handshake success and transitions to MapViewController

    func showSplashViewController() {

        showSplashViewControllerNoPing()



        delay(6.00) {

            self.showMenuNavigationViewController()

        }

    }



    public func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(

            deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)

    }



    /// Displays the MapViewController

    func showMenuNavigationViewController() {

        guard !(rootViewController is Home) else { return }



        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let nav =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeTab") as! Home

        nav.willMove(toParentViewController: self)

        addChildViewController(nav)

        if let rootViewController = self.rootViewController {

            self.rootViewController = nav

            rootViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)



            transition(from: rootViewController, to: nav, duration: 0.55, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve, .curveEaseOut], animations: { () -> Void in



            }, completion: { _ in

                nav.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

                rootViewController.removeFromParentViewController()

                rootViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)

            })

        } else {

            rootViewController = nav

            view.addSubview(nav.view)

            nav.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        }





    }



    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {

        switch rootViewController  {

        case is LaunchViewController:

            return true

        case is Home:

            return false

        default:

            return false

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it had over 13 errors and wouldn't build.  Not sure why