# Video in UIWebView full screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, youtube

I am showing a youtube video link in UIWebview. When I tap on video it starts playing in iPhone Media pLayer. When I tap on full screen mode in media player it stretches the video in AspectFill mode. Is it possible to change media player mode to AspectFit.

Comment: also visit this link  :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977330/play-video-by-default-in-full-screen

Answer (score 0):

The [**MPMoviePlayerViewController**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html)  class implements a simple view controller for displaying full-screen movies. Unlike using an MPMoviePlayerController object on its own to present a movie immediately, you can incorporate a movie player view controller wherever you would normally use a view controller. For example, you can present it using a tab bar or navigation bar-based interface, taking advantage of the transitions offered by those interfaces.

Comment: I dont have instance of MPMoviePlayerController, it bydefault open from webview.